# Site wide HTTP Header for Tags

Tags: iis, http-headers

I have just inherited a massive old HTML site that I want to track on Google analytics. It's nearly a 1000 pages of good old '90s html.

I've been running a web server for many years but am not a coder in any particular language although I do edit my PHP config files and my HTML files, install and configure modules in Mediawiki, phpBB and Drupal. I am currently on Svr2016, IIS10. For this HTML site, how would I include the Google tag (or any other tracking tag) in the header on every page served from my IIS console?

I need a pretty cut and paste or point and click solution.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to modify the html page header by using IIS console manager without coding. In my opinion, the most easily way to open the html file and add the include tag. If your php application has the master page, I suggest you could modify the master page.

Comment: Yup. Had though of that already. Using HTTrack I can include a new header in every file that is copied. I had hoped there was a method for IIS10 though. If I ever wanted to change it that's a lot of pages to edit. The charm of old HMTL 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using IIS and have SSI enabled (SSI= server side include).

I would create an include file (server side include - could be .shtml) and paste the google analytics or tracking. 
Then, I would find a file such as footer that’s used by all the other files and include it. 
Or maybe put it other common files like navigation that’s used site-wide.

See sample use/issues. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/244352/why-wont-ssi-work-in-iis

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Take a look at the HTML code on this site I inherited and am "restoring" - http://is.nshdpi.ca and see what I'm talking about.